# how can I assign a date in format string to a javascript date variable?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm registering a javascript in aspx.net

```
Dim script = "<script language = javascript>" & _
                           "window.setTimeout('ShowTime(true, [?????])', 1000);</script>"

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, "iniciar", script)
```

I must write a dateTime parameter in string format, but I'm not achieving the goal. I've tryed various time formats (Eg. 2011/02/10 17:05:00), without success. Ps: I know... when I try with only the date, its ok. But I need the time too. Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking for the string Date format options for javascript?  The code you posted does not appear to be relevant.

Comment: This will depend on how does the `ShowTime` javascript function expects as second parameter and what it is doing with it.

Comment: It's `type="text/javascript"`, not `language="JavaScript"`. And passing a string as the setTimeout callback is ev[ia]l.

Comment: I would like to mantain a certain time information for couting the time that a user takes to do an operation in my site. As I'm using asp.net, every postback call the pageLoad event, then my variable is reseted and the time couting breaks. This way, I think that I could give the inicial value for time countig to solve the problem. @Cris, @Darin Dimitrov. @ThiefMaster: Explaining - this is a piece of vb code. Statement is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript lacks a comprehensive string-based format mechanism.  Aside from manually piecing the date together using the Date object's methods like `getMonth` and `getFullYear`, one would have to create a script to do such formatting, or use one of the myriad existing functions on the internet.  Here is an excellent example:  http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format

Answer (score 0):

[Date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) is a great library for all date-related function in Javascript.